# Build .NET Core targeting both Core and Full .NET on MAC

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can I build a .NET Core app targeting both .NET Core and Full .NET by skipping Full .NET build and run?
I mean that I can build for both on Windows but be able to build and run only for Core on MAC.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use extra options in `dotnet` commands, such as `-f` for `dotnet build` to explicitly compile against .NET Core only on Mac,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build

Not sure if such an approach works for all other commands.